# How to keep point number when converting to a line

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a layer of point that I convert to a line with the plugin Point2One to be able to do apply a smoothing with the generalizer tool. It works well! then I convert my layer back to points using the vector tool extract vertices and when I look at the attribute table everything looks good except that all my points number became 201. The thing is I need the point numbers.

My point number is the field 6 in the image

[image]

I tried to duplicate them, add some letter before, add an other row of point number starting from 1 (mine does't), change the field type. Nothing worked I get 201 in all of these cases...

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE Maud! Have you tried `join attributes by location` between your old and your new pointlayer?